# how to increase only parent with out increase child projects

Tags: maven

```
    ***Parent   
    ***project1
    ***project2
    ****project3


<parent>
  <artifactId>xyz-application</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
  <version>2.3.1-snapshot</version>  
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-Library</artifactId>
<version>2.50.0.g</version>
```

after run the version set I run `mvn versions:set -newversion=2.3.2-Snapshot` from main parent pom

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>xyz-application</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <version>2.3.2-snapshot</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-Library</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2-snapshot</version>
```

i dont want to change version of project

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>xyz-application</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <version>2.3.2-snapshot</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-Library</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2-snapshot</version>
```

need versions `<version>2.50.0.g</version>`

it is changing all the project versions....

i dont want to change the project artifacts versions2.50.0.g...i want to change only parent versions with out changing project versions why because all my projects are in different versiosn.....

when we run this from main parent it is changing all the project versions to the new versions.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-N` flag? -N means none-recursive. It should not go into submodules, but I've never tried it with the versions plugin `mvn versions:set -N`

Comment: in the child projects also we have parent section....its changing parent section along with project version...i want t o change only parent section and dependency section not project version